# How-to sign an iOS configuration profile generated programmatically in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, configuration-profile

## Context

I have a iOS app (Swift) that generates some MDM iOS configuration profiles (*.mobileconfig) programmatically.

App users enter some informations, then app generates a configuration profile "on-the-fly" with the user-specific data, open in Safari on localhost server via Swifter ([GitHub link](https://github.com/httpswift/swifter)), so the user can click this link and install it on its iOS device.

In short: this profile contains in its payload only a webclip (safari shortcut).

Everything works fine, the configuration profile link opens the iOS Settings app that asks the user to install this profile on its device.

My problem is that this programmatically generated **profile is not signed**. So the user **is warned by iOS** that the profile is not signed and he must do several additional actions to confirm the profile installation.

I would like that the generated profiles to be signed, **so the user can install them more easily and quickly**.

## Questions

- is it possible?
- if yes, is it possible with Swift (or Objective-C)?
- if yes, how can I do that?

I read some ressources about signing configuration profiles, but I don't have any skills about signing, certificates etc.

That's not clear for me!

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: From MDM documentation: To sign a profile, place the XML plist in a DER-encoded CMS Signed Data data structure.

Comment: Can you help me with some example please? I don't have any skills about signing, certificates etc.